# php: convert pdo content to mysqli

Tags: php, jquery, pdo, mysqli

I am using a nice piece of code to reorder db content using [drag and drop](http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/title/sort-table-rows-jquery.html). I can get it to work locally by enabling the PDO extension in the php.ini file but my hosting package (shared) does not allow PDO and MySQLi simultaneously. I am unfamiliar with PDO and I would appreciate any help in rewriting the following segment to work with MySQLi, if possible. 
Thanks.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['orders'])) {

} else {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
}

$orders = explode('&', $_POST['orders']);

$array = array();

foreach($orders as $item) {
    $item = explode('=', $item);
    $item = explode('_', $item[1]);
    $array[] = $item[1];
}

try {

    $objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'pw');
    $objDb->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $key = $key + 1;
        $sql = "UPDATE `artwork` 
               SET `listorder` = ?
               WHERE `id` = ?";
               echo $sql;

        $objDb->prepare($sql)->execute(array($key, $value));        
    }

    echo json_encode(array('error' => false));

} catch(Exception $e) {

    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));

}
```

Comment: That's basically a single query you have to translate there. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation? Find another host. Going from PDO to mysqli is not a good idea, because you will waste time porting code into a less portable state.

-- Edit --

You can try the following code snippet, if it doesn't work it should get you started. I couldn't test it because none of my servers have mysql* modules compiled.

```
$dbo = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo sprintf('Unable to connect: ErrNo: (%d), ErrMsg: (%s)', mysqli_connect_errno, mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    $key = $key + 1;

    $sql =  "UPDATE `artwork` SET `listorder` = " . (int) $key . "  WHERE `id` = " . (int) $value;

    $dbo->query($sql);
}

$dbo->close();
```

You can get more information on mysqli query and other functions [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

Anyway, good luck.

Comment: +1 Sounds like a garbage host. Not to mention PDO is the de facto "correct" way to operate on a DB as compared to the less robust mysql* extensions

Comment: Agree 110%. The only porting from PDO to anything that should occur is if you are moving to an ORM. Going from PDO to mysql* is like going from filet mignon back to top ramen.

Comment: I may end up doing that as the feature is rather important and I need to start getting to grips with PDO also, but I'd love to see if or how the above could be done for MySQLi. I appreciate that I need to get stuck into tutorials but a quick fix to the above would be great if it's possible as I am unlikely to change hosts immediately (Client's account).

Comment: @caseyc: Updated post with snippet.

Comment: @Mike MySQLi also has prepared statements, no need to go all the way back to the stone age. ;)

Comment: Lol, post it up, been so long since I've done mysqli, I'm rusty as hell. :(

Comment: Thanks for that Mike Purcell. I'll give it a go and get back with a post tomorrow. The table id is primary and auto incremented so it's ok; the listorder is just a copy.

Comment: @caseyc: Ya man my apologies, I mis-read the order of entry for $key and $value in your OP, I have since corrected.

Comment: @Mike: Worked a treat. I'm weak on objects in general so I wasn't going to arrive at your solution in a hurry. Much appreciated